# ¿Detectar cambios en un documento Word/PDF C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, pdf, net, docx

Estoy intentando detectar cuando un documento Word o PDF es diferente a la version que esta cargada, tengo un formulario en el que mediante un OpenDialog se carga un documento el cual puede ser remplazado.
No cuento con un metodo para detectar si la nueva version que el usuario cargue efectivamente contiene cambios. Si el usuario quiere remplazar el documento es necesario cambiar el nombre para que sea replazado de otra manera si el documento que quiere remplazar tiene el mismo nombre que el nuevo no realizo el remplazo.

Podria hacerlo mediante un checksum o algun hash de los documentos y compararlos ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para saber si algún archivo fue alterado o si mantiene su autenticidad se cuenta con una técnica de seguridad llamada `checksum` (suma de comprobación) la cual usa unos algoritmos específicos para comprobar la integridad del archivo y tener la certeza de que este no ha sido manipulado y es totalmente confiable.

el `checksum` es un algoritmo, llamado `hash criptográfico`, que se ejecuta en un archivo, la cual nos devolverá un valor, este valor se usará para comprobar con los valores que se obtengan de la verificación del archivo de origen y el actual. Si coinciden podemos estar seguros de que el archivo es el mismo sin modificaciones.

Checksum usa diversos algoritmos para comprobar la integridad de un archivo, los más comunes son:

> MD5 MD5 (Message-Digest Algorithm 5 - Algoritmo de Resumen del Mensaje
> 5)

Es un algoritmo `criptográfico de 128 bits` y es uno de los más usados actualmente. (Poco seguro)

> SHA-1 SHA-1 (Secure Hash Algorithm - Algoritmo de Hash Seguro)

Es un `conjunto de funciones hash` y es muy usado en aplicaciones de firma electrónica ya que genera códigos hash entre 160 a 254 bits.

> SHA-256 (Muy seguro)

Es uno de los algoritmos más usados en diversos protocolos por su alcance a nivel de seguridad, tales como `TLS, SSL, PGP, SSH`, entre otros. SHA-256 siempre cuenta con `64 caracteres` independiente del tamaño de la longitud del archivo donde cada digito es una letra de la A hasta la F y cada uno representa 4 bits de información por lo cual 64 caracteres x 4 bits= 256 bits lo cual aumenta su nivel de protección.

> SHA-512 (Muy seguro y 50% más rápido que el SHA 256)

Este comportamiento de velocidad lo obtiene en equipos que utilizan CPU con arquitectura x64 y sistemas operativos de 64bits.

[MSDN Información del algoritmo SHA-512 y ejemplo de uso](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha512managed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1)

Información sobre benchmarks y tests acerca de ambos algoritmos.

[¿ Es más rápido el algoritmo SHA-256 vs SHA-512 ?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/sha512-faster-than-sha256)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo mediante la fecha de creación y de ultima modificación de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\file.word/pdf");
DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\file.word/pdf");
```

Utilizando la fecha es una manera sencilla de saber si el archivo ha sido modificado.